# cpanel db backup with cron in windows

Tags: database, laravel, cron, cpanel

I want to take backup of my database daily with `cPanel` cron job

I've tried this solutions but didn't work for me

`mysqldump -uCpenelUsername -pCpanelPassword dbname > testDB/$(date +\%m-\%d-\%Y-\%H.\%M.\%S)-name.sql`

Can someone please guide me where I'm making a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using your sudo user name sudo DB password, which is the  root DB password, without that you cant export, next is the path, use something like this,

```
home/your_server_name/testDB/$(date +\%m-\%d-\%Y-\%H.\%M.\%S)-name.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

This command works perfect for me

`` date=`date -I`; mysqldump -u cPanelusername -pcPanelpassword dbname > /home/cPanelusername/testDB/xbackup_$date.sql ``